# Laravel log max file is not working

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2, I just deployed my code on server. I am using laravel logs on the daily basis and so in the `confg/app.php` i added these two lines

```
'log' => 'daily'
'log_max_files' => 15
```

But it is not keeping the logs of 15 days. It is always keeping the logs of last 5 days only which is default file size. Am i missing something to add..?

Comment: Have you cleared the caches?

Comment: yeah, i cleared the cache from server

Comment: Try php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear

Comment: @SR_ If i clear the config, then sometimes my controller codes not taking the value from .env, my website is live, so is any other option

Comment: ok then after performing above two hit php artisan config:cache command

Comment: Any chance there are queue workers running that would have the old config and need to be restarted?

Comment: Self note but maybe someone will find this worthy:
if you want to make log files kept for unlimited time and delete it manually, set the log_max_files to 0

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/7b992836275e09ed63c63fe33ca9993e515e6c5d/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php#L41

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you should run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

to cache your configuration.

In addition you should run

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

to make sure your queue workers will see the changes.

Additionally you should make sure there are valid permissions to log files to make it possible to delete them.

Comment: I am curious - can you explain why caching config would help? Do you mean there might be some old config currently cached?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, old configuration might be cached and when there is no `log_max_files` set by default Laravel will use 5 as far as I remember

Answer (score 1):

You have to run this command on your terminal

```
php artisan config:cache
```